# What is the DAX equivalent of Row Number() in SQL?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

I want to add an column in my DAX query output which will give the cumulative row number starting from 1? I want to generate this dynamically for any DAX query that I run. How can I achieve this without much performance impact?

I have a dataset like this:

[image]

I have created a measure for ContractValue as SUM([Value]).
The expected output is to get the dynamic row number generated for the aggregated results as well. For example:

[image]

Comment: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Dynamic-Row-Numbers/td-p/52671

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. But here instead of adding the Index column at the table level, Can we do something similar at runtime for the DAX output?

Comment: What defines the order of the rows in your ouput?

Comment: The Contract Value measure.

Comment: Unless you are talking about Ranking on a specific known set of field, something similar with RANKX can be achieved. You won't have a true row_number, you can have repetition ou missing values. DENSE vs SKIP options. RANK = RANKX(ALL('mytable'[Confidential]),SUM('mytable'[Value]),,DESC,DENSE)
If you want this to be generic for the whole model... There isn't a straight foward way to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes I tried a lot of options but we cannot achieve a straight forward row number in a generic way.

Answer (score 1):

You can first create your summary table:

```
ContractSummary =
GROUPBY (
    Contract;
    Contract[Confidential];
    "Contract Value"; SUMX ( CURRENTGROUP (); Contract[Value] );
    "RowCount"; COUNTX ( CURRENTGROUP (); Contract[Value] )
)
```

Next you can add a column to your table:

```
Expected Result =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( ContractSummary[Contract Value] );
    FILTER (
        ContractSummary;
        ContractSummary[Contract Value] >= EARLIER ( ContractSummary[Contract Value] )
    )
)
```